# Zip file on external server and download the zip on my server

Tags: php, zip

Below is my requirement, but I am not able to understand how would I do it using PHP.

1. User selects some list of files and click on download.
2. The request goes to the external server (using HTTPS) where the files are located.
3. It zips those set of files which are selected by user in step 1.
4. Then the zipped file get downloaded on the user's system.

I explored different options, like using SSH2, curl, file_get_contents. But I am unable to determine how all this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
create upload.php

<?php
    $error = "";        //error holder
    if(isset($_POST['compress'])){
        $post = $_POST;    
        $file_folder = "files/"; //Folder where files are exists   
        if(extension_loaded('zip'))
        {   // Checking ZIP extension is available
            if(isset($post['files']) && count($post['files']) > 0){ 
                $zip = new ZipArchive();            // create zip class object 
                $zip_name = time().".zip";          // Zip name
                if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){        // Open zip object
                    $error .=  "* Zip file could not be create<br/>";
                }
                foreach($post['files'] as $file){              
                    $zip->addFile($file_folder.$file);           // Adding files into zip
                }
                $zip->close();
                if(file_exists($zip_name)){
                    // push to download the zip
                    header('Content-type: application/zip');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
                    readfile($zip_name);
                    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
                    unlink($zip_name);
                }

            }else
                $error .= "* Please select file to zip <br/>";
        }else
            $error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension<br/>";
    }
?>



Create index.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Download As Zip/RAR</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Create a Compress file with PHP</h1></center>
<form name="zips" method="post">
<table>
<?php
if($error!='')
{
    ?>
    <center><h5 style="color:red;"><?php echo $error; ?></h5></center>
    <?php
}
?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="car.jpg"></td><td><img src='car.jpg' width='50'></td><td>Car.jpg</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="plane.jpg"></td><td><img src='plane.jpg' width='50'></td><td>Plane.jpg</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="bike.jpg"></td><td><img src='bike.jpg' width='50'></td><td>Bike.jpg</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="compress" value="compress"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ziparchive** to create the zip file, and you can make your code download the zip file.

Reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php